# Issue with show / hide icons collapsing all divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code which contains some nested DIVs.

The DIVs have Plus and Minus Font Awesome icons to expand and collapse them.

You can use the buttons at the top of the page to toggle visibility of the DIVs.

The blue button and / or plus/minus icons can toggle visibility of the parents (`Activities` and `Animals & Nature`).

The green button toggles visiblity of the "child" divs which contain sub-headings such as `award-medal`, `event` etc.

The problem I have is that when it comes to toggling visibility of the child divs with the green plus/minus icons, if you e.g. click on the green minus for the `award-medal` heading, it also collapses the div for `event`.

I wondered if there is any way to split out the collapse functionality there, so that the green toggle button still works as it does now, but so that the individual gree plus/minus icons control the visibility of each div the icon is related to.

I can sort of see why the code works as it does now, but cannot get my head around how I would have to change the JS code to be able to achieve what I'm trying to do.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggleparent').addClass('toggle-open');
  $('.heading > a').on('click', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 if ( $(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-minus') ) {
   $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.submenu').css("display", "none");
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.submenu').addClass('closed');
   if ( $('.submenu.closed').length == $('.menu').length ) {
  $('.toggleparent').removeClass('toggle-open');
   }
 }
 else if ( $(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-plus') ) {
   $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.submenu').css("display", "block");
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.submenu').removeClass('closed');
   $('.toggleparent').addClass('toggle-open');
 }
  });
  $('.toggleparent').on('click', function(){
 if ( $(this).hasClass('toggle-open') ) {
   $('.heading').each(function() {
  $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
  $(this).parent().find('.submenu').css("display", "none");
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.submenu').addClass('closed');
   });
   $('.toggleparent').removeClass('toggle-open');
 }
 else{
   $('.heading').each(function() {
  $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
  $(this).parent().find('.submenu').css("display", "block");
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.submenu').removeClass('closed');
   });
   $('.toggleparent').addClass('toggle-open');
 }
  });
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.togglechild').addClass('toggle-open');
  $('.subheading > a').on('click', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 if ( $(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-minus') ) {
   $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.indent').css("display", "none");
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.indent').addClass('closed');
   if ( $('.indent.closed').length == $('.menu').length ) {
  $('.togglechild').removeClass('toggle-open');
   }
 }
 else if ( $(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-plus') ) {
   $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.indent').css("display", "block");
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.indent').removeClass('closed');
   $('.togglechild').addClass('toggle-open');
 }
  });
  $('.togglechild').on('click', function(){
 if ( $(this).hasClass('toggle-open') ) {
   $('.subheading').each(function() {
  $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
  $(this).parent().find('.indent').css("display", "none");
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.indent').addClass('closed');
   });
   $('.togglechild').removeClass('toggle-open');
 }
 else{
   $('.subheading').each(function() {
  $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
  $(this).parent().find('.indent').css("display", "block");
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.indent').removeClass('closed');
   });
   $('.togglechild').addClass('toggle-open');
 }
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  background: #fff;
  margin-top:20px;
}

h1.heading {
  font: 'Oswald';
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

td { background: #f1f1f1; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; border-right:1px solid #ccc; padding:20px; margin:5px; border-top:1px solid #fff; border-left:1px solid #fff; }



.wrappingmapping {
 margin:20px 0 0 20px;
 border-radius:85px;
 overflow:hidden;
 border:10px solid #fff;
 box-shadow:0 0 10px #999;
}


.menu {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.submenu {
  padding: 20px;
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  -45deg,
  #999,
  #999 10px,
  #888 10px,
  #888 20px
);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.green {
 color:#28a745;
}

.heading {
  color: #000;
  background: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.subheading {
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.indent {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.icon {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  *width: 99.94877049180327%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gallery.grid li {
  margin: 2px 5px;
}

.gallery.grid li {
  margin: 2px 5px;
  display: block;
}

.gallery.grid li:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.gallery.grid li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 6px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  background: #fff;
}

.gallery a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  
  <div class="container-fluid">

  <div>
   <span class="toggleparent btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-selector="parent_">Toggle Parents</span>
   <span class="togglechild btn btn-success btn-lg" data-selector="child_">Toggle Children</span>
  </div>

  <hr />

  <!-- parent start -->
<div id="activities" class="menu">
 <h1 class="heading">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> Activities <span style="color:#ccc;"> [57] </span>
 </h1>
 <div id="parent_activities" class="submenu">
  <!-- child start -->
  <h4 class="subheading">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus green" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> award-medal <span style="color:#ccc;"> [6] </span>
  </h4>
  <div id="child_award-medal" class="indent">
   <ul class="gallery grid">
    <li>
     <a href="#"><img title="military medal - ️" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f396.svg" class="icon" role="presentation"></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div> <!-- /indent --> 
  <!-- child start -->
  <h4 class="subheading">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus green" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> event <span style="color:#ccc;"> [19] </span>
  </h4>
  <div id="child_event" class="indent">
   <ul class="gallery grid">
    <li>
     <a href="#"><img title="jack-o-lantern - " src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f383.svg" class="icon" role="presentation"></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div> <!-- /indent --> 
 </div> <!-- /submenu --> 
</div> <!-- /menu --> 
<!-- parent end -->




<!-- parent start -->
<div id="animals-nature" class="menu">
 <h1 class="heading">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> Animals & Nature <span style="color:#ccc;"> [106] </span>
 </h1>
 <div id="parent_animals-nature" class="submenu">
  <!-- child start -->
  <h4 class="subheading">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus green" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> animal-amphibian <span style="color:#ccc;"> [1] </span>
  </h4>
  <div id="child_animal-amphibian" class="indent">
   <ul class="gallery grid">
    <li>
     <a href="#"><img title="frog face - " src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f438.svg" class="icon" role="presentation"></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div> <!-- /indent --> 
  <!-- child start -->
  <h4 class="subheading">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus green" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> animal-bird <span style="color:#ccc;"> [12] </span>
  </h4>
  <div id="child_animal-bird" class="indent">
   <ul class="gallery grid">
    <li>
     <a href="#"><img title="turkey - " src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f983.svg" class="icon" role="presentation"></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div> <!-- /indent --> 
 </div> <!-- /submenu --> 
</div> <!-- /menu --> 
<!-- parent end -->




 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by `.parent().find('.indent')` it find all `.indent`, but what you need to find `.next` element with `.indent` class not all, so you should use `.parent().next('.indent')`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggleparent').addClass('toggle-open');
  $('.heading > a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-minus')) {
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
      $(this).parent().parent().find('.submenu').css("display", "none");
      $(this).parent().parent().find('.submenu').addClass('closed');
      if ($('.submenu.closed').length == $('.menu').length) {
        $('.toggleparent').removeClass('toggle-open');
      }
    } else if ($(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-plus')) {
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
      $(this).parent().parent().find('.submenu').css("display", "block");
      $(this).parent().parent().find('.submenu').removeClass('closed');
      $('.toggleparent').addClass('toggle-open');
    }
  });
  $('.toggleparent').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('toggle-open')) {
      $('.heading').each(function() {
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
        $(this).parent().find('.submenu').css("display", "none");
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.submenu').addClass('closed');
      });
      $('.toggleparent').removeClass('toggle-open');
    } else {
      $('.heading').each(function() {
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
        $(this).parent().find('.submenu').css("display", "block");
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.submenu').removeClass('closed');
      });
      $('.toggleparent').addClass('toggle-open');
    }
  });
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.togglechild').addClass('toggle-open');
  $('.subheading > a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-minus')) {
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
      $(this).parent().next('.indent').css("display", "none");
      $(this).parent().next('.indent').addClass('closed');
      if ($('.indent.closed').length == $('.menu').length) {
        $('.togglechild').removeClass('toggle-open');
      }
    } else if ($(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-plus')) {
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
      $(this).parent().next('.indent').css("display", "block");
      $(this).parent().next('.indent').removeClass('closed');
      $('.togglechild').addClass('toggle-open');
    }
  });
  $('.togglechild').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('toggle-open')) {
      $('.subheading').each(function() {
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
        $(this).next('.indent').css("display", "none");
        $(this).next('.indent').addClass('closed');
      });
      $('.togglechild').removeClass('toggle-open');
    } else {
      $('.subheading').each(function() {
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
        $(this).next('.indent').css("display", "block");
        $(this).next('.indent').removeClass('closed');
      });
      $('.togglechild').addClass('toggle-open');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

h1.heading {
  font: 'Oswald';
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

td {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

.wrappingmapping {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  border-radius: 85px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
}

.menu {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.submenu {
  padding: 20px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, #999, #999 10px, #888 10px, #888 20px);
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.green {
  color: #28a745;
}

.heading {
  color: #000;
  background: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.subheading {
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.indent {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.icon {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  *width: 99.94877049180327%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gallery.grid li {
  margin: 2px 5px;
}

.gallery.grid li {
  margin: 2px 5px;
  display: block;
}

.gallery.grid li:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

.gallery.grid li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 6px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  background: #fff;
}

.gallery a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div>
    <span class="toggleparent btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-selector="parent_">Toggle Parents</span>
    <span class="togglechild btn btn-success btn-lg" data-selector="child_">Toggle Children</span>
  </div>

  <hr />

  <!-- parent start -->
  <div id="activities" class="menu">
    <h1 class="heading">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> Activities <span style="color:#ccc;"> [57] </span>
    </h1>
    <div id="parent_activities" class="submenu">
      <!-- child start -->
      <h4 class="subheading">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus green" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> award-medal <span style="color:#ccc;"> [6] </span>
      </h4>
      <div id="child_award-medal" class="indent">
        <ul class="gallery grid">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img title="military medal - ️" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f396.svg" class="icon" role="presentation"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /indent -->
      <!-- child start -->
      <h4 class="subheading">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus green" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> event <span style="color:#ccc;"> [19] </span>
      </h4>
      <div id="child_event" class="indent">
        <ul class="gallery grid">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img title="jack-o-lantern - " src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f383.svg" class="icon" role="presentation"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /indent -->
    </div>
    <!-- /submenu -->
  </div>
  <!-- /menu -->
  <!-- parent end -->




  <!-- parent start -->
  <div id="animals-nature" class="menu">
    <h1 class="heading">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> Animals & Nature <span style="color:#ccc;"> [106] </span>
    </h1>
    <div id="parent_animals-nature" class="submenu">
      <!-- child start -->
      <h4 class="subheading">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus green" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> animal-amphibian <span style="color:#ccc;"> [1] </span>
      </h4>
      <div id="child_animal-amphibian" class="indent">
        <ul class="gallery grid">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img title="frog face - " src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f438.svg" class="icon" role="presentation"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /indent -->
      <!-- child start -->
      <h4 class="subheading">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus green" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> animal-bird <span style="color:#ccc;"> [12] </span>
      </h4>
      <div id="child_animal-bird" class="indent">
        <ul class="gallery grid">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img title="turkey - " src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/svg/1f983.svg" class="icon" role="presentation"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /indent -->
    </div>
    <!-- /submenu -->
  </div>
  <!-- /menu -->
  <!-- parent end -->




</div>
```